# Array syntax with AWK

Tags: awk, array

I am baffled at the response of these scripts.

Trial 1:

```
awk '{line_arr[$0] } END {for (line in line_arr) print line}' text_file
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Trial 2:

```
awk '{line_arr[$0] } END {for (line in line_arr) print line}' text_file
```

Output:

```
is some text.
Hello. Here
Lots of random
text.
```

File content:

```
$ cat text_file
Hello. Here
is some text.
Lots of random
text.
```

Why is the *index* of the array storing as an actual value?

Why is the second trial out of order?

Comment: I am not sure why I would put line as the index. line is just a iteration of array from the for loop. Someone else mentioned this to me and I tried it. It was just printing 4 blank lines, nothing else. I am confused by the array sytax mostly. The array order was unkown to me. Thanks.

Comment: What's your `awk` version?

Comment: What is your output in the first case? Is it output line number or the line content?

Comment: awk seems to be gawk 4.1.3-2

Comment: It is line number. On another file it is also a climbing pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this rare syntax, `awk` stores your lines in an ***[Associative Array](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-22)***. Thus it has no defined order. You reached an undefined behavior.

Here is how to get convinced: print the line number from the associative array itself:

```
$ awk '{line_arr[$0]=NR } END \
       {for (line in line_arr) print line_arr[line]"=>"line } \
      ' text_file

3=>Lots of random
1=>Hello. Here
4=>text.
2=>is some text.
```